Nikah Without Parents Knowledge
السَّلاَمُ عَلَيْكُمْ وَرَحْمَةُ اللهِ وَبَرَكَاتُهُ

I'm in love with a man since the last two years. We're 18 and 19
currently. Is it possible for us to get nikahfied after a few months
in order to not get sins because we talk to each other? We just want
to refrain from getting more sins. We want to get nikahfied
secretly and have a proper nikah in the presence of our parents
and relatives after we complete my studies. Meaning after 4 to 6
years. We don't really plan to indulge in sexual activities. We have a
few witness available already.

Kindly advice in accordance with Hanafi Fiqh, it will help us to arrive at a final decision.

A wali is not required for marriages according to the Hanafi school. Please view: https://islamqa.org/hanafi/daruliftaa/7744/divorced-woman-marrying-without-her-guardians-approval/
